# Failed to open stream: Permission denied - when trying to read from file

Tags: php, apache, chmod, chown

I have two files which i want read using php. One file is located in `/var/www/html` and the other file is located in `/svn/access/` (directory which i have created). I can read the file which is in `/var/www/html` but the other one cannot be read.

I get the following error message:

```
Warning: fopen(/svn/access/test): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/svnmanager/test2.php on line 5
```

I have given permission to all the directories and file using 'chmod' and 'chown'

```
chown -R apache:apache /svn*
chmod -R 755 /svn

chown -R apache:apache /svn/*
chmod -R 755 /svn/*
```

[image]

But i'm still getting that error, When i try to read from the path `/svn/access`. Why is this happening and how can i fix this ? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found myself a solution for this.
SELinux blocks httpd to write in any folder other than `/var/www/`. Therefore some configurations have to be made.

`yum -y install policycoreutils-python`

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/svn/access(/.*)?"
restorecon -R /svn/access
```

Comment: It is especially appreciatable that this solution does not disable SELinux altogether, but modifies it's policy to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

have you used sudo?

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /svn*
sudo chmod -R 755 /svn

sudo chown -R apache:apache /svn/*
sudo chmod -R 755 /svn/*
```

you may need to be a super user to change permissions

Comment: @CasperNine are you running any sort of panel like plesk? as the group may not need to be apache:apache it may need to be psacln: then the user as the ftp username. have you tried using ls -la in a folder that does work to see what group and user is set there?

Answer (score 0):

Always use 4 numbers, i had a lot of trouble because i forgot that. So 0755 would be my suggestion.

Comment: Adding 0755 didn't fix the issue :(